# A Kubernetes container and service question

Tags: docker, kubernetes, service

Our contractor worked out the application and the process building the Docker image of it. I am able to run it on a Google virtual machine and then open the application using localhost:8080. As instructed by the contractor, I had to run the following command to run the container on the vm:

`docker run --gpus all -p 8080:8080 imagename ./bin/pvpython share/paraview-5.9/web/visualizer/server/pvw-visualizer.py --content share/paraview-5.9/web/visualizer/www/ --port 8080 --plugins lib/paraview-5.9/plugins/StreamLinesRepresentation/StreamLinesRepresentation.so`

You can see there are many arguments in this command. Our goal is to run it in Google Kubernetes Engine. I have been searching and testing how to make those arguments work in the deployment yaml file in GKE without any luck. I was able to see in the pod's log that the directories (e.g.share/paraview-5.9/web/visualizer/server/pvw-visualizer.py) in the yaml file cannot be found.

I then tried to use Kompose to convert the original Docker Compose yaml file from the contractor to the Kubernetes yaml file. It seems it works because there isn't any log entries for the pod. So I went ahead to expose the workload as a LB service. When I tried to open the page, it said "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx didn't send any data". I also tried to expose it as Cluster IP service. Still no luck. I don't know how to diagnose at this moment.

Below is the Kubernetes yaml converted by Kompose:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.26.0 (40646f47)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: our app
  name: our app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: our app
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert
        kompose.version: 1.26.0 (40646f47)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: our app
    spec:
      containers:
        - args:
            - ./bin/pvpython
            - share/paraview-5.9/web/visualizer/server/pvw-visualizer.py
            - --content
            - share/paraview-5.9/web/visualizer/www/
            - --plugins
            - lib/paraview-5.9/plugins/StreamLinesRepresentation/StreamLinesRepresentation.so
          image: my image name
          name: our app
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          resources: 
            limits:
              nvidia.com/gpu: "1"
```

Here's my service yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: our service
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.26.0 (40646f47)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: our service
  name: our app
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: our app
    io.kompose.service: our service
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
```

Comment: can you share your service files? Also, it might be possible you're using HTTPS on an endpoint that is HTTP

Comment: Dear zer0, I just posted my service file as shown above. I tried both HTTPS and HTTP and got the same error. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: @CloudNewbie : Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.